# VS 2017 , функция toupper не принимает string

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Добрый день !

Подскажите пожалуйста. Использую IDE Visual Studio 2017 , хочу написать простую программу для вывода введенной информации с верхним регистром. Для преобразования использую функцию toupper(). Функция не видит мою переменную string.

[image: Мой код , и как ругается IDE]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Больше так не делайте - не выкладывайте эти копии экрана! Просто текст и сообщение об ошибке.
2. Функция [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) получает символ, а не строку целиком. А вы передаете ей именно строку. Работайте посимвольно.

Comment: Спасибо , разобрался благодаря вашему ответу , я впервые задавал вопрос , более скриншоты делать не буду.